# How would one multiply numbers with extremely high exponents of 10, on a calculator?

Tags: number-theory

The two numbers I wish to multiply are 6.6359516e+21 and 6456577120. However, I do not seem to be able to multiply these numbers, on my standard CASIO calculator. Could someone kindly give an insight as to how to multiply these numbers on a calculator, if it is, by any chance, feasible?

Comment: Use this property : $(a\times 10^b ) \times c = (a \times c) \times 10^b$.

Comment: I can do it with my ALGEBRA FX 2.0Plus

Comment: Enter the second number also in scientific notation : $$6.45657712e+09$$